# Angular4 CORS header contains multiple values

Tags: spring, angular, cors

please could somebody help to resolve issue:
backend spring application
web.xml

```
 <filter>
        <filter-name>corsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>package.controllers.auth.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>corsFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

filter

```
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*,*");
        httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
        httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials");
        httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "10");
        System.out.println("---CORS Configuration Completed---");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

Angular frontend:

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + '/url', JSON.stringify(user), options)
      .map(response => response.json())      
  }
```

Browser return issue:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values

Comment: Change this:

    `httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*,*")`

…to just this:

    `httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")`

Browsers require the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` value to be a single `*` wildcard character (to indicate any origin is allowed) or else a single origin; e.g., `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://foo.com`.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing same issue. Root cause was that  cors header was going multiple times. I commented out

```
httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");"
```

line.

I had only one security config class which looks like below. This class, solved my issue of cors.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            // your security config here
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.TRACE, "/**").denyAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and().httpBasic()
            .and().headers().frameOptions().disable()
            .and().csrf().disable()
            .headers()
            // the headers you want here. This solved all my CORS problems! 
           /* .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"))*/
            .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET"))
            .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600"))
            .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true"))
            .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin,Accept,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization"));
    }
}
```

In my case, i am just doing POC, and calling Rest resource from angular application. I was facing only issue in CORS . 
To solve only cors issue, bare minimum below code is also sufficient.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    }
}
```